# Android root access prevent App launch

Tags: android, root, launching-application

Does anyone know of a way to programmatically prevent the launch of another app (or list of apps) if you have root access?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can chmod the apk to 600 (not executable) the apps is in /system/app and /data/app

Comment: Thats exactly what I was thinking...but I wasn't sure if it would work...I wasn't sure how the app was formatted when it was unpacked from APK...is there an executable file?